# Trying to count the number of 'a' that are entered

Tags: character, counting

Whenever I try to run the following code to count my characters I constantly get zero instead of the number of characters I have inserted.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main() {

    int c;
    int count = 0;

    while ( (c = getchar() != EOF) && c == 'a' ) {
        count = count +1;
    }

        printf("Number of chara: %d", count);
    }
```

I have altered the code to instead only count whenever 'a' comes up, but still only get zero when I enter my characters and hit the return key.

Answer (score 0):

The condition of your while loop evaluates to false when the program reads a character that isn't an 'a', which ends the while loop. Since your program reads characters in the while loop, no more characters get read.

Try checking if the character is an 'a' inside the loop body before updating the counter instead of in the loop condition.

Answer (score 0):

The loop will stop because you set the c=='a'. Try to remove that in your code.

Try this one:

```
int c;
int count = 0;

while  (c = getchar() != EOF ) {
    count = count +1;
}

    printf("Number of chara: %d", count);
}`
```